# Is Dominic Toretto's Personal Code a factor in the Vin Diesel Babylon A.D.?

Tags: fast-and-furious-franchise, babylon-ad

I'm not suggesting that Toorop is Dominic, although there is an idea that "movie stars" tend to "play themselves" in every role *(Jared Harris contrasted this with "chameleon" actors who make every role distinct, Gary Oldman & Tom Hardy as examples.)*

Here's what I mean:

- In Babylon A.D. (2008) Toorop states that all a mercenary has is his balls and his word.  Toorop has given his word to deliver Aurora.
- During the arctic crossing, Aurora states that they have become family via their shared struggles.
- In NYC, Toorop & Aurora make sweet love, and she subsequently reveals she is pregnant and Toorop is the father.
- Toorop breaks his word, and does not deliver Aurora.

[It's been established that Toretto's personal code comes down to one thing: Family.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89987/what-is-dominic-torettos-personal-code)  Under the sometimes complicated system of warrior codes, there can be conflicting loyalties.  In this case, Toorop breaks his word, destroying his honor as a mercenary, because he has a higher loyalty he must serve: family.

- **Did the Babylon A.D. film change the story to make Aurora's fetuses Toorop's, or was this in the book?**

If this was not a factor in the books, where Vin was surely the person with the most power on that film, being the element that guaranteed box office and generates pre-sales of the distribution rights, did Vin influence the script to reflect his most successful franchise?

If so, can Dominic Torreto's personal code be said to have been a factor in the plot of the Babylon A.D. (2008) film?

Comment: in this case, given points by you it has connections with many other movies and basically it's good guy's rough act softened by the pretty girl at the end. See Taroop could be Frank Martin from the Transporter. So it could be Diesel following Statham

Comment: How are these movies even connected, is there anything concrete that suggests that? Many movies share this same plot theme - bad guy gives his word to deliver a person, fall in love with said person and fails to deliver. Doesn't mean they're all part of the same universe.

Comment: @Luciano That isn't what the question is positing, though. At no point the question suggests a story-wise connection beyond merely having the same actor. That's not the point the question is trying to make (even if that might admittedly be the first impression from just reading the title).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yes but what reason would a character in a movie have to be affected by another character from another movie?

Comment: @Luciano Supposedly being played by the same actor, according to the question. What the question is asking is if Vin Diesel exerted creative power over this film to change his character based on his character from another film. Making this about "Torreto's personal code influencing Babylon A.D." is merely a creative twist in the question's wording that leaps over a few intermediary causalities, rather than an actual suggestion of independent connection between the *characters*. This question is all about Vin Diesel and the production of *Babylon A.D.*, though.

Comment: This can only be answered by Vin Diesel himself or interviews with people involved in the production / writing of Babylon A.D. ...

Comment: @Luciano So? This is the case for a lot of questions. Guess we'll have to wait for them to either make an account here or, as happened with about 15,674 existing questions, people to do some research and either dig up a straight answer or draw some well-reasoned conclusions.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson that's what I meant, someone dig up the info

Comment: @NapoleonWilson That is an accurate assessment of the question--did Vin exert power to influence the script and his character, to keep it "on brand" for Vin.  (I have tremendous respect for him as a producer, and he's been very successful cultivating his career, which not all leading men are able to do for such an extended period.)  There are still a quite limited number of actors that can "open a movie", and Vin is definitely one of them, in regard to action cinema.

Answer (score 2):

The two films aren't even remotely connected.  The idea of family and honor is found throughout the history of movies.  This is like asking if Al Pacino's role in The Godfather had anything to do with his role in Scarface.  Both are gangster-related, both characters are steeped in family and honor (in fact, he also says the line, "There's only two things I have in this world; my word and my balls.  And I don't break 'em for nobody."), both eventually fell from grace.

Vin Diesel actually has a more diverse background than you're giving him credit for.  He was in Saving Private Ryan and showed none of the "character traits" you bestow on him.  He was also in The Pacifier, where he played a completely different type of character.  Action starts are often typecast, so their characters have similarities, but they also audition for those parts and, except in the case of Stallone who writes most of his movies, are not guaranteed to win a given role.  To think Babylon A.D. was re-written just because of the Fast/Furious franchise is giving Diesel way too much credit.

Comment: Aaah, but we have meta-art now, and Pacino's casting in Scarface may well have been influenced by his role in The Godfather, and carried a built-in reference to the previous role.)  Consider "About Schmidt" (2002) where Payne cast Jack Nicholson to imply a grandly theatrical, 3rd act meltdown, specifically so that the director could play with that expectation. (In the film, Nicholson's character ends up behaving, finally redeeming himself, to some degree, as a father.)

Comment: Also, I rewatched Private Ryan recently, and even in that film, Vin played Vin.  Pretty much identical to all of his other performances.  (Not knocking Vin, just that he's a movie star, like Arnold, as opposed to a serious actor like Tom Hardy.)